# Xamarin Forms Navigation stucks on WebService SomeMethodAsyncCompleted Event

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

Hi everyone i am using a WCF Soap Webservice and consuming it inside a Xamarin.Forms MVVM Client. (Mvvm light with [MvvmLightNavigationExtension](https://github.com/dhindrik/MvvmLightNavigationExtension).

The Problem is when i use the Async Methods from the Webservice and corresponding Completed Event in my ViewModel the Navigation stucks / the screen is not changing.

When i debug the current Navigation Page says to be my second page but the first Page is still showing.
I Also tried it with Messengers but that wont work eather.

Down Below is some example Code.

Fun fact: When i make a second Button/Command and navigate to my second page **after** i called the GetLoginResponseCommand i can navigate Back **two times** to the first page.

Its Probably some weird Threading/UI Thread thing but i don't get it.

```
public LoginViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, MyWebService service)
{
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    _myWebService = service;

    _myWebService.GetLoginInfoCompleted += MyWebServiceOnGetLoginInfoCompleted;
}

public RelayCommand GetLoginResponseCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _getLoginResponseCommand ?? (_getLoginResponseCommand = new RelayCommand(
            () =>
            {
                _orkaWebService.GetLoginInfoAsync(request);
            }));
    }
}

private void MyWebServiceOnGetLoginInfoCompleted(object sender, GetLoginInfoCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _navigationService.NavigateTo(VmKeys.ArtikelBestandKey);
}
```

Comment: What is in your `_navigationService.NavigateTo()`

Comment: Its GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Views.INavigationService

Answer (score 0):

Try to use async/ await in your async methods.

```
return _getLoginResponseCommand ?? (_getLoginResponseCommand = new RelayCommand(
        async () =>
        {
            await _orkaWebService.GetLoginInfoAsync(request);
        }));
```

Comment: It says Cannot await 'void'.
I added the Web Reference via right click add Service Reference on my Project references.

Comment: GetLoginInfoAsync has return type `void`?  The return type should be a `Task` or `Task<T>`

Comment: Well i cant change it because its auto generated by Visual Studio.

Its a PCL Project btw. I Also tried it on a shared Code Sample but there its also void type... 
Well i found another way around (what is not using it like this) but its still kinda sucks...

Comment: You can try to run it in a separate thread using `Task.Run()` or `TaskFactory`

Comment: FYI found the solution and posted it here.
Thanks for your Help because it was indeed a Threading problem!

Answer (score 0):

I Got it myself.

The `MyWebServiceOnGetLoginInfoCompleted` runs in an own Thread. But the `_navigationService` needs to be run on the UIThread.

(Same for `ContentPage.DisplayAlert` or `ContentPage.DisplayActionSheet`)

When you run it like `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => _navigationService.NavigateTo(VmKeys.ArtikelBestandKey));` it works like a charm!

```
private void MyWebServiceOnGetLoginInfoCompleted(object sender, GetLoginInfoCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => _navigationService.NavigateTo(VmKeys.ArtikelBestandKey));
}
```

Thanks to Rohit for leading me to the right solution.